# Does our heart have to work harder in hot or cold weather?

Tags: human-biology

In hot weather our perspiration is higher and often old people get tired faster when it is hot. But is there a relation between hot weather (sweating) and our heart if so what makes it have to work harder?

And does our heart have to work less (compared to hot) in cold weather where capillaries and vessels constrict, making it harder for the heart to pump blood.

Comment: If body temperature is higher, then yes, the heart will work harder to cool the body by pumping blood more quickly (to spread the heat more evenly). Likewise, the converse can be said about cooler body temperatures and the heart *not* pumping as hard as to retain heat. This is true, under the assumption that body temperature is dependent on environmental temperature. I think you will have a difficult time finding studies on this that do not involve rigorous physical activity as the reason for increased body temp, as most of them do, of which wouldn't provide the most relevent data, IMO.